# Python line.replace multiple strings

Tags: python

I am replacing the '2010' with a random number:

```
from random import randint
with open("data.json", "rt") as fin:
    with open("dataout.json", "wt") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(line.replace('2010', str(randint(1990, 2007))))
```

how can I replace two items in one code, that is:

```
fout.write(line.replace('2099', str(randint(1800, 1900))))
fout.write(line.replace('2010', str(randint(1990, 2007))))
```

Comment: So one line contains both 2099 and 2010 and you would like to replace both in one go instead of calling the function twice?

Comment: no they will occur on different lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two `replace()` method:

```
from random import randint
with open("data.json", "rt") as fin:
    with open("dataout.json", "wt") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(line.replace('2010', str(randint(1990, 2007))).replace('2099', str(randint(1800, 1900))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use `if` to check if your line contains `'2099'` or `'2010'` like this:

```
from random import randint

with open("data.json", "rt") as fin:
    with open("dataout.json", "wt") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            if '2010' in line:
                fout.write(line.replace('2010', str(randint(1990, 2007))))
            if '2099' in line:
                fout.write(line.replace('2099', str(randint(1800, 1900))))
```